# I would like to know how to define a metric to calculate 12 months moving average of a certain fact including current month

Tags: average, gooddata

I would like to know how to define a metric to calculate 12 months moving average of a certain fact including current month. The metric I defined as 'SELECT AVG('FACT') WHERE Month/Year(Date) BETWEEN {This - 12} AND {This}' hadn't worked expectedly but displayed natural averages for each month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this as just one number and not sliced by the month 'SELECT AVG('FACT') WHERE Month/Year(Date) BETWEEN **{This}-12** AND {This}' should work (put the -12 after date macro {This}).

Comment: https://support.gooddata.com/entries/30656927-7-Day-moving-average

SELECT( (SELECT SUM(個品割賦信用供与額) FOR PREVIOUS(年月, 1))+ (SELECT SUM(個品割賦信用供与額) FOR PREVIOUS(年月, 2))+ (SELECT SUM(個品割賦信用供与額) FOR PREVIOUS(年月, 3))+ (SELECT SUM(個品割賦信用供与額) FOR PREVIOUS(年月, 4))+ (SELECT SUM(個品割賦信用供与額) FOR PREVIOUS(年月, 5))+ (SELECT SUM(個品割賦信用供与額) FOR PREVIOUS(年月, 6))+ (SELECT SUM(個品割賦信用供与額) FOR PREVIOUS(年月, 7))+ (SELECT SUM(個品割賦信用供与額) FOR PREVIOUS(年月, 8))+ (SELECT SUM(個品割賦信用供与額) FOR PREVIOUS(年月, 9))+ (SELECT SUM(個品割賦信用供与額) FOR PREVIOUS(年月, 10))+ (SELECT SUM(個品割賦信用供与額) FOR PREVIOUS(年月, 11))+ (SELECT SUM(個品割賦信用供与額)))/12